# After login, use the user id from the object of the login in the resolvers

Tags: graphql, jwt, nestjs

Good day people

I am using nestjs with graphql

This is my AuthService:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    private usersService: UsersService,
    private jwtService: JwtService,
  ) {}

  async validateUser(username: string, password: string): Promise<User> {
    const user = await this.usersService.findOneByUsername(username);
    const isEqual = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    if (user && isEqual) {
      return user;
    }

    return null;
  }

  async login(user: User) {
    return {
      access_token: this.jwtService.sign({
        username: user.username,
        sub: user.id,
      }),
      user,
    };
  }
}
```

And this is my Events Resolver:

```
@Resolver((of) => Event)
export class EventsResolver {
  constructor(private readonly eventsService: EventsService) {}

  @Mutation((returns) => Event)
  createEvent(@Args('createEventInput') createEventInput: CreateEventInput) {
    return this.eventsService.create(createEventInput);
  }

  @Query(() => [Event], { name: 'events' })
  findAll(@Args('userId', { type: () => Int }) userId: number) {
    return this.eventsService.findAll(userId);
  }

  @Query(() => [Event])
  findEventsByDate(
    @Args('userId', { type: () => Int }) userId: number,
    @Args('eventStartDate', { type: () => Date }) eventStartDate: Date,
  ) {
    if (eventStartDate) {
      const startDate = formatISO(new Date(eventStartDate), {
        representation: 'date',
      });

      return this.eventsService.findEventsByDate(userId, startDate);
    }
  }

  @Query(() => Event, { name: 'event' })
  findOne(@Args('id', { type: () => Int }) id: number) {
    return this.eventsService.findOne(id);
  }

  @Mutation(() => Event)
  updateEvent(@Args('updateEventInput') updateEventInput: UpdateEventInput) {
    return this.eventsService.update(updateEventInput.id, updateEventInput);
  }

  @Mutation(() => Event)
  removeEvent(@Args('id', { type: () => Int }) id: number) {
    return this.eventsService.remove(id);
  }
}
```

Each query need the user id to work correctly but this in no good, so I want to grab that id from the response of the login and use in the resolver, what is the correct way to do this?

I try to create an interceptor to grab the id from the context but I am either doing it wrong or is not the correct way

Answer (score 0):

The standard pattern is to save the jwt `access_token` on the client when it is returned from the `login` mutation then include it as a `header` in subsequent requests to the GraphQL server. The GraphQL server's `context` function should look at the headers and set the `user` object when it sees a valid signed jwt. Resolvers that require authentication can then check the context to see if the resolver is being requested by an authorized user.

Unfortunately it is not possible (or at least very impractical) to execute a login mutation and an authenticated query in a single request as the query will run in parallel with the login mutation and no headers will yet have been set.

Comment: Thanks for you response, so basically save the token in the front, add as a header in the graphql config that I have in the front and then every query or mutation that need the user_id will take from that configuration header?

Comment: That's correct. I wrote up an [example](https://michelfloyd.hashnode.dev/jwt-authentication-in-apollo-v4-part-1) awhile back. That one is for Apollo v4 and a react-native client but the principles are the same.

Comment: Great, then I'll try out what write in the example, thanks for the information!